# Opening apps with custom protocols (twitter://, instagram://) in Cordova/PhoneGap on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova

I can't seem to use custom URL protocols to open the apps that are installed on an iPhone; even with InAppBrowser installed.

For example:

```
// Instagram
window.open('instagram://user?username=jgillick', '_system', 'location=no');

// Twitter
window.open('twitter://user?screen_name=jgillick', '_system', 'location=no');
```

Both of these things do absolutely nothing. They don't even open the InAppBrower window.

Facebook is a really interesting one. Instead of using a custom protocol, if you try to access `https://www.facebook.com/<facebook ID number>` on your phone, the Facebook app will automatically take over (you can use [this tool](http://findmyfacebookid.com/) to find your facebook ID). This works when I put it in Safari on my iPhone, but doesn't in the InAppBrowser, it just opens the app browser and directs me to the logged-out version of that page.

```
// Facebook
window.open('https://www.facebook.com/763639132', '_system', 'location=no');
```

I'm at a complete loss for getting this working.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the `window.open('...', '_system')` method suddenly just started working. I'm not sure why it wasn't before.

Answer (score 0):

For me that wasn't giving anything useful

```
window.open('...', '_system')
```

what worked was:

```
window.location = 'instagram://media?id=' + id;
window.location = 'fb://post/' + id;
```

of course those native apps have to be installed, otherwise no action will happen.
this might come handy https://github.com/ohh2ahh/AppAvailability